# Mapping attachment is throwing the error in Elasticsearch 7.7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-7

I try to map the field as user defined field - "attachment" in elastic search like below

```
"file": {
            "type": "attachment",
            "fields": {
              "content": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "author": {
                "type": "text",
                "store": true
              }
}
```

Attachment mapping like below,

```
"attachment": {
            "properties": {
              "author": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: RemoteTransportException[[3cfb4e163654][172.17.0.2:9300][indices:admin/create]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Failed to parse mapping [mappings]: No handler for type [attachment] declared on field [file]]; nested: MapperParsingException[No handler for type [attachment] declared on field [file]];
```

**[Failed to parse mapping [mappings]: No handler for type [attachment] declared on field [file]]**

I already have the ingest attachment plugin added to the elastic search plugin and it is available when I list the plugin in elastic search.

What is wrong with my mapping?

Please help me on this ?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: can you share the entire mapping.json so that I can try myself

Comment: Yes, `mapping` is partial. @harry add mapping for `file` in `attachment`

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja https://codeshare.io/5gYjjB I have shared the complete json

Comment: @Gibbs https://codeshare.io/5gYjjB I have shared the json, Could you let me know the modification I need to do in this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed the plugin and it is available when you list it. But you are getting the error `No handler for type [attachment] declared on field [file]`

Reason:

You are expecting to add `attachment` as a type. But that's not true.

> Ingest attachment plugin does not add a new type.
> But adds an ingest processor

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-attachment.html)

You need to add this as a processor in your pipeline.

**Update1:**

Just installing the plugin will not solve the problem as it is invalid type. I am able to reproduce this error.

[Reference](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/no-handler-for-type-attachment-declared-on-field-content/117375) Documentation is the above link is the one which I attached in the original answer.

[Nice explanation about the way of usage](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/plugins/ingest-attachment.asciidoc)

Comment: If I understand correctly, After installing the plugin, I don't need to do the mapping rather I just want to set pipeline like this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-ingest-put-pipeline.html 

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to set the pipeline. You can use that for java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671455/elasticsearch-put-role-api Could you check this pls

Comment: Thanks @Gibbs, Any luck on getting this?