# Elasticsearch put role API

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, elasticsearch-7

I started using the create role API and it works as expected : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-role.html

I got the list of default roles in elasticsearch, `/_security/role` but I don't know to create the following roles and not able to find the proper docs for it.

I want to segregate the user based on the following needs,

1. Role which has the privilege to perform only READ / WRITE in all the indices in Elastic Search (This role should not have privilege to CREATE / DELETE indices
2. Role which has the privilege to perform only operations on Kibana
3. Role which has the privilege to perform only operations on Logstash

Answer (score 1):

> I want to segregate the user based on the following needs,
>
> - Role which has the privilege to perform only operations on Kibana
> - Role which has the privilege to perform only operations on Logstash

when [Creating / Updating a role](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-role.html), you can find all valid privileges in [security privilege](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-privileges.html) of elasticsearch 7.x documentation then add / delete some of them into the role you update.

The role setup below should cover typical use cases of Kibana and Logstash :

- For Logstash user

  - add `manage_index_templates` to cluster privilege list
  - add `create_index` and `index` to indice privilege list, for each index pattern
  - you may need `create` or `create_doc` in the indice privilege list, in case that you generate `_id` field of a document externally (instead of auto-generated ID by elasticsearch)
  - assign the new role you created to whatever users you like

```json
# Quick example, with POST request /_security/role/my_logstash_role

{
  "cluster": ["manage_index_templates"],
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "logstash-*", "YOUR_INDEX_PATTERN_2" ],
      "privileges": ["create_index", "index"],
    }
  ],
  "applications": [
    {
      "application": "YOUR_APP_NAME",
      "privileges": [ "YOUR_APP_PRIV" ],
    }
  ],
}
```

- For Kibana user

  - add `read` to indice privilege list, for each index pattern
  - assign the new role you created, **and built-in role `kibana_system`** to whatever users you like, note `kibana_system` includes (1) a cluster privilege named `monitor` and (2) access permissions to some index patterns e.g. `.kibana*`, `.reporting-*`, `.monitoring-*` , which are required by Kibana.
  - if you also use [DevTool console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/console-kibana.html) of Kibana to interact with elasticsearch REST API, you may need to add few more privileges like `write`,`delete`,`manage` ...etc to the role, which highly depends on the API endpoints you attempt to call.

```json
# Quick example, with POST request /_security/role/my_kibana_role

{
  "cluster": [],
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "logstash-*", "YOUR_INDEX_PATTERN_2" ],
      "privileges": ["read"],
    }
  ],
  "applications": [
    {
      "application": "YOUR_APP_NAME",
      "privileges": [ "YOUR_CUSTOM_APP_PRIV" ],
    }
  ],
}
```